# How to copy files that have same name as the folder they are in?

Tags: 20.04, copy

There are files that have a pattern like `name/name.ext` inside subdirectories. There are many files with the same extension inside the subdirectories but I want to copy only the files which have pattern mentioned. what is the command to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a clever way to do this using a shell like zsh that has more extensive filename generation (globbing) capabilities, but if you can't do that, then the GNU `find` command supports regular expression matching with backreferences for at least some of the regextypes. Ex. given

```
$ tree .
.
├── bar
│   ├── 1.xyz
│   ├── 2.xyz
│   └── 3.xyz
├── baz
│   ├── 1.xyz
│   ├── 2.xyz
│   ├── 3.xyz
│   └── baz.xyz
└── foo
    ├── 1.xyz
    ├── 2.xyz
    ├── 3.xyz
    └── foo.xyz

3 directories, 11 files
```

then

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/([^/]+)/\1\.xyz$'
./baz/baz.xyz
./foo/foo.xyz
```

which you can modify to copy like

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/([^/]+)/\1\.xyz$' -exec cp -n -t path/to/newdir/ {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will copy ./name/name.txt to . (your currernt directory)

```
cp name/name.txt .
```

Comment: name/name.ext is a pattern. `name` can be anything. its a placeholder.